# Transfer School on Resume

Tags: resume

I attended college for my bachelor's degree from 2010 to 2013. After my freshman year I transferred to a different school, which I graduated from at the end of 2013. The problem is, my resume listed the years that I attended school (2010-2013), but only listed the school I graduated from, even though I only attended that one from 2011 to 2013. Is this in error, or is only mentioning the school I actually graduated from okay? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

10 years later, a prospective employer doesn't care too much about other schools, only that you graduated from one of them. All you need on your resume is something similar to the following;

Education: BSc Underwater Basketweaving from Oxford University, 2013

Comment: I was just asking because I have applied to jobs with that resume, and am waiting to hear back from them. (I have interviewed for one, but the resume question didn't come up). I was wondering if having to explain about the transfer would count as having had wrong information on my application and affect my chances of getting said job.

Comment: Nah. What they care about, if anything, is what school you graduated from, what you studied there, and what your GPA was -- but realistically, after a decade in the workforce, they are ***MUCH* more interested in where you worked and what you did at work; that's a far better indication of your current skill level. Academics at this point are mostly interesting for "Oh, they've had some exposure to X; that might be useful."

Comment: I would agree that outside of a specific situation, where the hiring official (or someone with hiring power) went to your first school, nobody would care about you attending a college you didn’t actually graduate and receive a degree from.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're in a regulated profession (illegal to practice without a degree), employers don't normally look into the degree. Even if they do, you were correct in naming the diploma-granting school and skipping wherever your first year was.

This is for industry jobs. On an academic CV, you would list every school and specific years spent there.

Answer (score 1):

#### You can put whatever you like on your resume

Putting the degree-granting school would be normal.  Don't put years attended, just the year the degree was granted.  In your case, it's fine, certainly not a problem if the company looks into it. I would expect your transcript from the finishing school to include the initial school transferred credits as well.

If the application process asks for all education institutions, you would be expected to put all schools attended.